# mock atLeastOnce with concrete value, the rest not important

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, xunit

The question is in `PHP`, but applies to any language using the `xUnit` framework.

I want a mock, that expects 140 calls to method `jump`.
I need to verify, that **at least once** there is a call with 500 as parameter.
I don't care if all the calls are 500, but I need at least one that is called with 500.

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Trampoline', ['jump']);

$mock->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
     ->method('jump')
     ->with($this->equalTo(500))
     ->will($this->returnValue(true));

$sportsman->setTramploine($mock);
$sportsman->jumpToRandomHeights($times = 140); // this calls Trampoline->jump
// I need to verify the sportsman had jumped 
// to the height of 500 at least once out of the 140 jumps he is performing
```

In the current code, the test fails after the first invocation of `jump` because the first invocation had a value different of `500`, meaning the `atLestOnce` here only indicates that the method should be called, but not that it should be called with specific value among other calls.

---

## Solution

The missing piece of information was using callbacks inside the `with`. Thanks to edorian's answer below this is what worked out:

```
$testPassed = false;

$checkMinHeight = function ($arg) use(&$testPassed)
{
    if($arg === 500)
        $testPassed = true;

    // return true for the mock object to consider the input valid
    return true;
}


$mock = $this->getMock('Trampoline', ['jump'])
    ->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
    ->method('jump')
    ->with($checkMinHeight)
    ->will($this->returnValue(true));

$sportsman->setTramploine($mock);
$sportsman->jumpToRandomHeights($times = 1000); // this calls Trampoline->jump
// I need to verify the sportsman had jumped 
// to the height of 500 at least once out of the 1000 jumps he is performing


$this->assertTrue($testPassed, "Sportsman was expected to 
    jump 500m at least once");
```

Comment: Very helpfull but sadly doesnt seems to work when using objects :( 
Im getting error like this `"Foo Object &000... is not instance of expected class "Closure".`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can but the best implementation withing PHPUnits mocking API, that I could come up with, still looks quite creepy.

Another way to solve this is a little more readable way would be to create your own subclass of `Trampoline` and implement it there.

#### But for the challenge:

Assuming this class:

```
<?php
class FancyMocking {
    function doThing($value) { }
}
```

and that we have `$x` calls and one of those has to have a `$value > 200`:

---

```
<?php

class FancyMockingTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testAtLeastOfMy200CallsShouldHaveAValueGreaterThan500() {
      $maxInvocations = 200;

      $mock = $this->getMock('FancyMocking');
      $mock->expects($this->exactly($maxInvocations))
        ->method('doThing')
        ->with($this->callback(function ($value) use ($maxInvocations) { 
            static $invocationCount = 0;
            static $maxValue = 0;

            $maxValue = max($value, $maxValue);
            /* The assertion function will be called twice by PHPUnit due to implementation details, so the *2 is a hack for now */
            if (++$invocationCount == $maxInvocations * 2) { 
                $this->assertGreaterThan(200, $maxValue, 'in 500 tries the max value didn\'t to over 200');
            } 
            return true;
        }))
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($value) { 
            return $value >= 200;
        }));
     for($i = $maxInvocations - 2; $i; --$i) { 
          $mock->doThing(50);
     } 
     var_dump($mock->doThing(250));
     var_dump($mock->doThing(50));
    }


}
```

This will produce:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.9 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.bool(true)
bool(false)


Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.75Mb

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

Meaning the call with 250 returns true an the whole test case works.

#### If it fails:

To make it fail we change `var_dump($mock->doThing(250));` to `var_dump($mock->doThing(70));` and run it again:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.9 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Fbool(false)


Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) FancyMockingTest::testAtLeastOfMy200CallsShouldHaveAValueGreaterThan500
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:doThing> when invoked 200 time(s)
in 500 tries the max value didn't to over 200
Failed asserting that 70 is greater than 200.

.../FancyMockingTest.php:29

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

---

The solution that doesn't use PHPUnits mocking API would be something like

`class FancyMockingFakeImplementation extends FancyMocking`, using that instead of the mock and writing the custom logic there.

Comment: Actually `with callback` was what I've been missing. I went through the entire [list of constraints](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertThat.tables.constraints) and didn't see this one. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the link and for saying that. I wasn't aware that i was missing and will add it to the list :)

Comment: Than I'm glad we could be helpful to each other.